# Customizing QGIS plugins

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, plugins

Is a user legally allowed to make changes to available plugins according to his needs? e.g. changing UI, code etc but not the licenses and other info.

Comment: I think so, that doesn't mean anything legal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer: Yes.**

**Longer answer:**

QGIS and its plugins are licensed under GPL (GNU General Public License), version 2 or later. This license allows anyone to modify QGIS and its plugins, as long as you follow the specified conditions. See the [full text](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/appendices/appendices.html) of GPL for those conditions.

Licensing requirements for QGIS plugins are explained on [this blog post](http://blog.qgis.org/2016/05/29/licensing-requirements-for-qgis-plugins/).

> QGIS is Open Source Software and provides a great platform for third parties to distribute additional functionality to users through our plugin system. QGIS is licensed under the GPL version 2 or greater. ...
>   Under the terms of this license, it is a requirement that all plugins distributed via http://plugins.qgis.org (or through other repositories that may be self-hosted) should comply with the GPL version 2 or greater license.

Follow [this link](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/appendices/appendices.html) for the full text of GPL (GNU General Public License) version 2, as provided in the current (version 3.4) QGIS User Manual. Here's what it says about modifying programs:

> You may modify your copy or copies of the Program or any portion of it, thus forming a work based on the Program, and copy and distribute such modifications or work under the terms of Section 1 above, provided that you also meet all of these conditions: (see full text of GPL version 2, section 2 for list of conditions)